# How to create table in Octave with border?

Tags: octave

I want to create a table which looks like this [Table01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XEkY.png).
Where each column is a vector.

I tried with Octave `data frame` package but it is not generating table as I expected (With border)
Previously I tried with `[t,I_X,I_Y] = table(x,y)` which is also not satisfactory.

How can I generate table like the sample I provided and store them in format pdf in a directory?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you want something similar to `uitable` in MATLAB. Unfortunately, I don't think that has been implemented yet. However, I think I've found a solution that might help you. Here's the output I get for an example matrix `m=magic(4)`:

[image]

If that is what you want, then keep reading! So, first, install the `miscellaneous` package. If using Ubuntu, you can just do that with

```
apt-get install octave-miscellaneous
```

Now, all you have to do is (well,you might run into a small problem, but I'll adress that in a bit):

```
pkg load miscellaneous
m=magic(4);
textable(m,"file","/tmp/file.tex","clines","rlines");
```

And voilà, you have the matrix expressed in latex code in `"/tmp/file.tex"`, that you can compile with `pdflatex` , or alternatively, just copy paste it into something like [this](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) to get an image of the table.

**Potential problem you might run into.** Note that this seems to apply in octave version `4.2.2` which is the one I'm using, so, maybe you wont encounter that problem with your version. When using `textable`, you might get an error of the style

```
error: value on right hand side of assignment is undefined
error: called from
textable at line 111 column 5
```

If that happens, this is because the function `textable` (whose code you can find in `textable.m`, you can just use `$ locate textable` on Ubuntu) seems to use an obsolete (or different) interface to the `inputParser` object that it uses internally. So, if that happens, just go to line `111` of `textable.m` and replace

```
p = inputParser;
p = p.addSwitch ("clines");
p = p.addSwitch ("rlines");
p = p.addParamValue ("math", "X", @ischar);
p = p.addParamValue ("file", "matrix.tex", @ischar);
p = p.addParamValue ("align", "r", @(x) any(strcmpi(x, {"l", "c", "r"})));
p = p.parse (varargin{:});
```

with

```
p = inputParser;
p.addSwitch ("clines");
p.addSwitch ("rlines");
p.addParamValue ("math", "X", @ischar);
p.addParamValue ("file", "matrix.tex", @ischar);
p.addParamValue ("align", "r", @(x) any(strcmpi(x, {"l", "c", "r"})));
p.parse (varargin{:});
```

and you're set to go.

Comment: That's because you should do this as superuser, just to `sudo <whatever editor you are using> <path to your textable.m>`, or just run `sudo su` and edit the file, save, exit the editor, then exist that last terminal with `ctrl+d`.

Comment: That was great! 
But unfortunately i need to generate the table automatically, not manually (converting the latex file in pdf).
Is there any way that at least in png format i can get the table?

Comment: @MohammedAtta  Cool, but concerning automating that task, as I said I don't think that you'll be able to do better than that with octave. You can however chain those things inside a bash script: call your octave code, and then run the `convert` command to get a png (this might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/50170/how-to-convert-pdf-to-image). If you are not already familiar with bash just read a quick tutorial and this  will become clearer for you I think.

Comment: Can you help me with the textable command to generate the example i provided? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MohammedAtta Sure, just edit your question with what you have tried and what specifically is being problematic for you.

Comment: The problem is how can i use different column vector for different column. And how to label the row name and column name by using your `textable` function?

Comment: @MohammedAtta  I'm not sure what you mean about different column vectors, do you mean vectors of different sizes? For this and also for naming rows, I don't think that `textable` is the right tool, I would just try editing the generated latex file using `sed` or similar regular expression based tools.

Comment: That means I want to store a column vector in one column (in the table), another column vector in another column of the table, in this fashion.

Comment: @Ash, the last miscellaneous was 2014 and then input parser has changed significantly since then. You should file a bugreport on savannah

Comment: @Andy, sure, will do.